# general sibling not work on hover

Tags: html, css

Why general sibling not work on hover? I try with all way, even try to make it use jQuery but CSS in jQuery I don't know how make transition duration

```css
.filter h5,
.filter span {
    color: #808391;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.work div.current h5,
.work div.current span {
    cursor: auto;
}    
.filter h5:hover
.filter span:hover + h5,
.work div.current h5{
    color: #fff;
}  

/* general sibling here not work */
.filter span:hover,
.filter h5:hover ~ .et,
.work div.current span {
    color: #ed4040;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="current filter" filter=".brainstorming">
        <span class="icon-genius et"></span>
        <h5>Brainstorming</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The span with class `et` is before the h5. The general sibling combinator only works in the forward direction.

Comment: Your comment of @davecar21 does not reflect the original question. Please update or clarify your question to match your comment, so everybody knows what you want. thx

Answer (score 0):

using CSS General Sibling Selector will target all the succeeding elements after it, and will not be able to target the elements before it.

You can try using JQuery `.siblings()` so you can be able to target all the sibling elements.
And then using `.mouseenter` and `.mouseleave` to create the transition.

```js
$( "h5" )
.mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).siblings().css({
  color: "#ed4040",
  transition: "all 1s ease"
  });
})
.mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).siblings().css({
  color: "black"
  });
});
```

```css
.filter h5,
.filter span {
    color: #808391;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.work div.current h5,
.work div.current span {
    cursor: auto;
}    
.filter h5:hover
.filter span:hover + h5,
.work div.current h5{
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="current filter" filter=".brainstorming">
        <span class="icon-genius et">SPAN</span>
        <h5>Brainstorming</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but i cant make transition duration in jquery css

Comment: @muhammadseleman you wanted to create a transition on all general sibling element when `.second` is hovered?

Comment: @muhammadseleman I see. Please see my updated answer and hope it helps.

Comment: Glad to help. Please upvote and mark my answer if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to take the hover of the parent and only select the class .et for change.

```css
.filter h5,
.filter span {
    color: #808391;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.work div.current h5,
.work div.current span {
    cursor: auto;
}    
.filter h5:hover
.filter span:hover + h5,
.work div.current h5{
    color: #fff;
}  

/* general sibling here not work */
.filter:hover > span.et{
    color: #ed4040;
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="current filter" filter=".brainstorming">
        <span class="icon-genius et">colorschange</span>
        <h5>Brainstorming</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```